# Example of ggplot2 stat_summary_hex using alpha aesthetic mapping?

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha

I'm plotting customer churn using the `ggplot2` `stat_summary_hex` function.

```
stat_summary_hex(aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = Churn),
   bins=100, colour = NA, geom = "hex", fun = function(x) sum(x))

ScaleFill <- scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "orange", na.value = NA)
```

The stat_summary_hex is plotted over a basemap from `get_map` so I would like to set the `alpha` scale such that summary values close to 0 would have an `alpha` of 0.  However, it looks like `stat_summary_hex` does not acknowledge an `alpha` aesthetic.

Does someone have an example of `stat_summary_hex` with `alpha` mapping?

Comment: Thanks for the formating suggestions @Henrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around by setting `drop` = TRUE and then changing the `stat_summary_hex` function to return NA when the result was less than my threshold:

```
stat_summary_hex(aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, z = Churn),
  bins=100, colour = NA, geom = "hex", drop = TRUE,
  fun = function(x) if(abs(sum(x)) > 5) {sum(x)} else {NA})
```